# SQL Server Reporting Services Permission Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, permissions

So we have an SSRS SQL 2008R2 server (AServer) that we have deployed some reports to.  The report in question runs on AServer and runs a stored proc on BServer to get its dataset.  When running the report, it errors out with the following

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'ReportData'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'pSomeStoredProc',
 database 'SomeDb',      schema 'dbo'.
```

My biggest issue is that it doesn't tell me at what level the permission was denied.  Does the account the report is running under on AServer not have the credentials to get over to BServer?  Can it get into   BServer, but still not have the perms to run that exact sproc?  Are the privileges of the user actually viewing the report being delegated over to BServer (I've seen similar voodoo happen with IIS)?

**What I've Tried and Failed At:**

My starting point was to check the SQL logs in msdb to see where an auth failure might have occurred.  No such luck was found when drudging through those logs.  I was expecting something like "INTRA\sqlserviceaccount doesn't have sufficient permissions to run SomeDb.SomeProc".

My second goal was to make sure the account running sql reports was also listed on the remote server.  It wasn't, so I found it in AD and added it.  I also added it to the db in question as a db_datareader and db_datawriter(<== not necessary).

The third attack was to make sure the RSExec role was on the remote server.   That didn't work either and I kind of got lost on what I was actually doing other than junking up my server's config.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work backwards in Report Manager from the report (or shared dataset):

1. Find the data source on which the shared dataset or report depends. This example is showing the data source for a shared dataset.

[image: Data Source for shared dataset]

2. Navigate to the properties for that data source. Locate the credentials section and find the configured user name. If `Windows integrated security` is selected, user credentials are being passed from the <kbd>Client Browser</kbd> → <kbd>Report Server</kbd> → <kbd>Database</kbd>. The below example is showing the data source credentials are stored in the report server.

[image: Data Source properties]

3. Back on the SQL Server database instance, locate the database and database user to which the login from step 2 is mapped. Grant this user `EXECUTE` permission on the stored procedure in question.

Comment: @Byron Eargle Holy jumping jacks, that was it.  When I looked at the privvies on the sproc itself, I didn't see the sqlservice acct that I thought I had.  I followed steps 1 and 2 and then completed step 3 and now it behaves correctly.